# How to stop addthis.com plugin or javascript while loading a page using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my application one page is loading addthis.com plugin/javascript file if I click Menu button clicked. My network Admin was blocked facebook.com through firewall but addthis.com was integrated with graph.facebook.com.

I don't want to load specific(addthis.com plugin) javascript file in Page load at runtime while running automation script using selenium webdriver with java,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless the reference for the file(addthis.com plugin) is removed from the HTML file.

Comment: Hi Sudharsan, may be is it possible using javascript function like onload function.    (or)                  FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
  fp.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");